# GPIO relay signal cross turns to all relays staying on after Darlington added

Tags: gpio, relay, hat, signal

[image]I have 4 [Sunfounder 2 channel relays](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E0NTPP4) 7 of which that I'm using to control some things on my aquarium. I suspect that I may have wired them up wrong somehow though. The behavior I'm seeing is as follows;

### if I open either Drain Pump/Fill Pump relay

1. The corresponding relay opens but if the ATO relay is open, it will
   close.
2. Closing either Drain Pump/Fill Pump relays has no effect on the ATO relay

### If I close the ATO relay

1. The Fish Feeder relay opens.
2. Inversely if I open the ATO relay the Fish Feeder relay closes.

### Sample code for opening and closing relays called from the command line

```
const Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;    
const drain_relay = new Gpio(7, 'out');
const fill_relay = new Gpio(8, 'out');
const feed_relay = new Gpio(14, 'out');
const ato_relay = new Gpio(18, 'out');

drain_relay.writeSync(0) //closes the drain relay
drain_relay.writeSync(1) //opens the drain relay
```

Similar `writeSync` calls passing `0` to close or `1` to open the other relays are made.

These were just a couple of the anomalies I found. There could be more.
On my Raspberry Pi hat I connect the 4 pin GND to ground and VCC to +5V and IN1 and IN2 to GPIO pins. Could the signal be jumping pins on the hat? Or is there something else I'm missing?

### UPDATE 6/6/18

I followed some direction that I received on the Raspberry Pi Forum [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=214622&sid=bc0a9f09702c10f22ec506603e7ccb46&start=25). The instruction I got was to add a ULN2003A Darlington transistor between gpio OUT and relay IN. I added this in between as instructed there. But now all relay LEDs stay on. When I command the relay open or closed the LED changes from bright to dim or dim to bright with no relay click indicating the relay itself had changed.

### Update 6/8/18 8:54am EDT

Just checked voltage output between `Gnd` to `IN1` and `Gnd` to `IN2` pins on relay board having relays 4 and 5 at the four pin connector with the relay disconnected. Voltages were as follows;
note: open and closed states are assumed because my relays aren't connected and haven't been actuated since adding the Darlington.

### Relay |  State  | PIN |  Voltage

```
 4    post boot  IN1     600mv
 4       Open    IN1     1.7mv
 4      closed   IN1     900mv
 5    post boot  IN2     600mv(Reset to 1.7mv post Relay 4 actuation)
 5       Open    IN2     1.7mv
 5      closed   IN2     900mv
```

### Questions

- Shouldn't I be seeing 5V when relays are closed?
- If I understand correctly the relays should be closing when voltage goes to zero. Is 1.7V enough to keep the relay LED lit and prevent the relay from closing?
- Do these seem like voltage numbers I should be expecting to see given my hardware and inputs?

### Update 6/8/18 6:22pm EDT

I took the two hats off my Pi and started going through my wires looking for a loose connection or something. I found a 5v wire on my new hat that, while the solder joint looked good, the wire seemed to move pretty freely compared to the others near the solder joint.

While I was there fixing that I knew I had left a couple of the 5v and ground wires that went to the 4 pin connectors on the relay boards on my original hat when I moved the ULN2003A , the GPIO signal wires and the ULN2003A OUT to relay IN wires to the new hat. I decided to bring those 5v and ground wires over to the new hat as well. This way I have all my relay related connections on one hat and sensor related connections on the other.

After putting everything back together the relay lights no longer lit up on boot. Good!?! Maybe? My relays still weren't actuating with my commands. And now there are no changes to the LED lights. they just stay off.

I disconnected the 4 pin connectors from the relay boards and began checking them with the volt meter. I no longer had 5V across any of the VCC GND pins. But when I probed GND to IN pins and toggled the associated GPIO I still got a voltage reading between zero and 900mv.

Comment: We need a schematic and photos of the wiring.

Comment: you might want to include the program/script you are using to control the relays.

Comment: @ShreyasMurali I'm just using https://github.com/fivdi/onoff. I call `new Gpio(14, 'out')` for example and then use the `.writeSync()` method to set it to either `1` or `0` to open or close the relay.

Comment: Could you clarify A and B map to which relays (fill_pump/drain_pump/fish_feeder/ato) ? (PS: the colors used on the wiring diagram are bit confusing. [typically](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36317/standard-wire-colors) black represents ground, red is +5V, yellow is +12V, and white/blue/green/orange etc are for GPIO signals)

Comment: Looking a bit closer at the wiring diagram, looks like there are 3 yellow wires, one is a ground, one goes to IN1 (fillpump) of the relay board 1 on the LHS and last one to IN2(ato) of the board on the RHS. my guess is (1) you might have swapped two signals in the actual wiring compared to the diagram (2) and/or there is some bug in the script you are using. it would help to include your script as is. Also found a relevant [link](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=2_Channel_5V_Relay_Module) that shows a RPi with this relay module you could use to test your script

Comment: @ShreyasMurali sorry for the non standard wire colors. I was trying to work with what I had on hand. But they are colored and connected as diagramed with the exception of the yellow wire coming from the `IN2` `Fish Feeder` relay. I had to splice a piece of black onto it to reach the `gpio 14` screw connection on the hat.

Comment: I'm bit more confused now. According to the schematic, relay labelled fish_feeder is connected to `IN1 -> (blue line) -> GPIO18` and relay labelled ATO is connected to `IN2 -> (yellow line) -> GPIO14`. the script however maps fish_feeder to `GPIO14` and ATO to `GPIO18`. which relay is what now ? Are the labels ATO and Fish Feeder incorrectly swapped on the diagram or in the code ?

Comment: The Fish Feeder and ATO relay labels were mixed up in the schematic. It's fixed now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78113/discussion-between-shreyas-murali-and-brad-w).

Comment: If you want an answer you still need to add a circuit schematic, no one can tell what is happening with that maze of wires. Adding a " Darlington transistor" is unlikely to help, especially as you don't specify how it was added. The relays claim to require 15-20 mA - the GPIO can source 16mA. Using modules with Optocoupler is pointless - the relay should supply all the isolation you need. These are inappropriate relay modules; a simple module driven logic levels would be more appropriate

Comment: This is a wiring problem, I use these relays in production settings exactly as you have without additional drivers and they work without a hiccup. @Milliways the optoisolator is useful, it doubles as a logic translator (it is sensitive to 3V3 input) and relay coil driver , the extra isolation is common

Comment: Looking a bit closely at your circuit diagram/pciture I noticed you have the jumper that shorts RY-VCC and VCC (on the 3 pin header). As you driving a "heavy load", you'd want to try removing the jumper & provide an external power to RV-VCC as recommended [here](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=2_Channel_5V_Relay_Module#Schematic):

VCC and RY-VCC are also the power supply of the relay module. When you need to drive a large power load, you can take the jumper cap off and connect an extra power to RY-VCC to supply the relay; connect VCC to 5V of the MCU board to supply input signals.

Comment: @ShreyasMurali can you recommend an appropriate external power supply for the application?

Comment: the voltage and current rating (+safety margin) of the combined load on the relays (pump(s) and fish feeder in your case) would decide that. you could start with a bench power supply or invest in a smps, something that looks like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14098) but rated for your relay/load. you could also poke around on aliexpress/amazon/ebay and find something cheaper.

Comment: Wait, the relays aren't directly supplying power to the fish tank equipment. They're only acting as a switch that interrupts power supply to turn them on and off. I thought you meant I needed to add an external power supply to actuate the relays.

Comment: yes. you're right. I went over the schematic again and realized I was a bit confused (for some reason i thought the RY-VCC went to the red wire on the relay o/p side) . I however found a relevant article [here](https://arduinoinfo.mywikis.net/wiki/ArduinoPower#Optically-Isolated_Relays) i hope you find something helpful there.

Comment: Brad, I've run my entire grow tent with 24V and 12V pumps for months using PiMoroni Automation Hat and AdaFruit FeatherWing Non-Latching relay. I started with relays such as yours and had unpleasant experiences with them. I currently favor the FeatherWing because it is easily replaceable. These relays are mechanical and wear out after a few months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning the problem I was having was relays actuating by a GPIO OUT signal that was not directed at them.

On the Raspberry Pi Forum user pcmanbob pointed out that my relays were designed to be actuated by 5v but the GPIO OUT signal that I was using to actuate them was only 3.3V He suggested adding a ULN2003 transistor which I soldered onto the Pi EZConnect hat shown.

This was when I went to all relays closing at boot and none of them responding to any GPIO signal. They Just stayed on.

After some breadboard testing with the ULN2003 I was able to get the relays to actuate according to the appropriate command but when I moved the setup back to the Pi EZConnect hat all relays still closed at boot.

The cause was the way the breadboard section of the Pi EZConnect solder pin holes were laid out.

[image: Pi EZConnect layout]

All pins going across the breadboard section of the Pi EZConnect are connected. Therefore the ULN2003 was being shorted/bypassed between its metal tabs across from each other.

The fix for me was to switch to a different hat with no connection between pins and make my own solder bridge between the wires and the nearest metal tab of the ULN2003.

Answer (score 1):

Your pictures don't labelled the connections.  Perhaps you can let us know the wires connected to the relay modules.

[image: Aquarium relays]

Or you might to confirm if my guess below is correct.

[image: aqua connect]

I checked your photos and found the optocoupler 817C, and the resistors 1k and 512R.  So I guess your connection is something like below.

[image: Aqua schematic]

So is Step 1 below OK, Step 2 has a problem?

[image: relay problem]

In the above diagram, if GPIO is Low, relay is triggered/activated/switched "on", electrical circuit is "closed" (therefore electrical current flows), motor is switch "on".

Your "open" seems to mean my "on", your "closed" means my "off".  I am still confused.  Let me try again.

Do you mean that if you run the following statements:

```
drain_relay.writeSync(0) //closes drain relay (drain pump, drain LED on)
sleep 1 second
ato_relay.writeSync(0) //closes ATO relay (ATO pump, ATO LED switched on)
sleep 1 second
```

You expect drain LED turned on in Second One, then both ATO and drain LEDs turned on in Second Two.  But the problem is that in Seconds Two, drain LED is turned off unexpectedly?

[image: NB0109opne001 v0.3]

/ to be continued, ...

**Appendices**

A1. [SunFounder 2 Channel DC 5V Relay Module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E0NTPP4)

SunFounder 2 Channel DC 5V Relay Module with **Optocoupler Low Level Trigger** Expansion Board for Arduino UNO R3 MEGA 2560 1280 DSP ARM PIC AVR STM32 **Raspberry P**i

Relay interface board, and each one needs **15-20mA Driver Current**

Equipped with high-current relay, AC250V 10A ; DC30V 10A

Standard interface that **can be controlled directly** by microcontroller (Arduino, **Raspberry Pi**, 8051, AVR, PIC, DSP, ARM, ARM, MSP430, TTL logic)

Indication LED's for Relay output status

Comment: Whether the relays are wired normally open or normally closed doesn't seem relevant to the issue I'm seeing. And the Gnd, IN1, IN2 and VCC are clearly visible on the relay boards of the first schematic image I posted.

Comment: I am a bit confused.  I don't know why NO and NC wiring is not irrelevant.  Perhaps I missed something.  Let me read you post again to find out.

Comment: OK.  So for all 4 relays, you only used COM and NO.  The NCs are left unconnected.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: `.writeSync(0)` after any relay name closes the relay allowing current to flow and "turning on" the target device. `.writeSync(1)` called on the same relay will open it interrupting power to the target device and "turning it off".

Comment: I'm seeing relays close (turn on) other than the one I'm commanding to close even as the commanded one closes.

Comment: I'm going to suggest we pause your analysis of the situation. i think I may have found the solution but I need to purchase some items to test the theory that has been presented to me. Basically the relays are actuated on 5v. But raspberry pi gpio only outputs 3.3v. The suggestion that has been made to me is to place a Darlington driver such between the gpio and the IN1/IN2 of the relay to boost the output voltage. Trying to actuate them with only 3.3v is likely causing a voltage fluctuation that is causing the irregular behavior.

Comment: OK. So I will pause my analysis.  In case the Darlington driver does not work, or other problem arises, I am happy to carry on.  Happy relaying.

Comment: OK, I followed some direction that I received on the Raspberry Pi Forum here. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=214622&sid=bc0a9f09702c10f22ec506603e7ccb46&start=25 . the instruction I got was to add a ULN2003A Darlington transistor between gpio OUT and relay IN. I added this in between as instructed there. But now all relay LEDs stay on. When I command the relay open or closed the LED changes from bright to dim or dim to bright with no relay click indicating the relay itself had changed.

Comment: Brad, I think it might be useful to partition the diagnosis by unhooking the relays and verify the outputs directly with a multimeter or if you can LEDs on a breadboard. This would help establish whether the issue relates to the relay or to everything else. WDYT?

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics I actually did that and confirmed 5V at the IN pins  that connect to my relay boards. Right now I'm wondering if I need a separate 5V power supply for the relays, currently I'm pulling 5V from the 5V Pi pins, or if I need to do something different with the jumper between VOC/VCC on the relay boards, currently they have a jumper between them in place.

Comment: Hmm "pulling from the 5V pins" makes me worry a bit. I power my Pi via GPIO at 5.2V from an LM2596 buck converter from 12V to guarantee sufficient current at that voltage. I also use Pi only relays (the Amazon link has people complaining about intermittent failure on your relays). This is all hypothetical.

Comment: Do you have a link to the relays you use?

Comment: Suggesting anyone connect the Pi GPIO to 5V (even through LED) is irresponsible. When "OFF" the full 5V will be applied to the GPIO.

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics: I guess OP's "Pulling 5V from 5V Pi Pins" means getting 5V power from the 5V power pin of the Rpi's 40Pin connector of GPIO block.

Comment: @BradW: Are you sure you wired the ULN2003 correctly?  You may like to compare with my ULN2803 wiring just uploaded. WARNING: ULN2003 Pin 9 is COM (to connect to Vcc), but ULN2803 Pin 9 is Ground (to connect to Ground)! My wiring diagram is just a draft.  You might like to double check, and use it at your own risk.

Comment: @BradW: For ULN2803, I suggest to get the 3v3 power from the 3V3 power pin of Rpi's 40pin GPIO block connector (There are two kinds of pins in the 40 pin connector: 3V3 and 5V power pins, and 3V3 IO pins).  I assume you are using Rpi3B or B+, whose 3V3 power pin can give more than 100 mA (so I was told, you better double check, and try it at your own risk). I ALWAYS use my own independent 3V3 and 5V power supplies (so I won't make any wrong connection by mistake), and NEVER take power. from the Rpi's 3V3/5V power pins..

Comment: @Milliways I would like to learn from your comment--I'm powering all my Pi's from GPIO2&4 having given up on the standard USB power. Can we discuss in chat or something? I'm not sure about how to split off this tangential conversation

Answer (score 1):

**In your initial diagram you do not show a GND connection to the module for Relays 6 and 7.**

**Lack of that ground would most likely cause the entire rest of the circuit to misbehave in deterministic ways that will show up as a definite pattern.**

The existence of the pattern is a clue; not necessarily the details of the incorrect behavior itself.

To solve this problem requires eliminating points of failure and striving towards the desired outcome.

**So first, check all of your wiring, correcting it as necessary**

**Then repeat your set of tests.  Hopefully it will just work.**

You'll learn something, you can be sure of that.  Just writing a comprehensive test plan is an education in itself.

If there is more information that you believe would be helpful in generating answers, please come back and edit the OP so we all have a better chance of helping.